# `NotImplementedError()` vs `NotImplementedError` - which is right?

Tags: python, exception

The question is simple. When defining an abstract method, should I raise `NotImplementedError()` or `NotImplementedError`? What's the difference?

Comment: The argument to `raise` is an instance of an exception, not the exception class itself. So you need `()` to call the constructor function.

Comment: Read any tutorial on raising exceptions, they all show the correct way to do it. There's nothing special about abstract methods that suggests anything different.

Comment: Read the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=raise#grammar-token-python-grammar-raise_stmt

Comment: [_"If \[the expression\] is a class, the exception instance will be obtained when needed by instantiating the class with no arguments."_](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) (cc @Barmar)